# What does "You are talking through your hat" mean?

Tags: phrase-request

I heard this phrase when I was following a hot loud debate by two Americans in a restaurant:

> You're talking through your hat!

What is an equivalent expression?

If you find it interesting for yourself and useful for audiences you can write about its etymology and usages too.

Comment: When the comments on this thread were deleted, snailplane's useful link was also removed. The rest were fine to be deleted but I thought I'd repost it: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/talking-through-your-hat.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Talking through your hat' means talking a lot about something without knowing much about it, like I am doing just now.